# Is possibile to import only specific a component instead of importing all library?

Tags: materialize

I am using materializecss v. 1.0.0 (beta) and i am trying to import only button component.
For the scss file I have no problem, but for js files I have some problems.

I have Imported these files folowing:

```
import Cash from 'materialize-css/js/cash';
import Component from 'materialize-css/js/component';
import Global from 'materialize-css/js/global';
import Materialize from 'materialize-css/js/buttons';
```

but is not correct because each wasn't build using import and export statement and button js don't find Global Component.

How could I import specific materialize component instead of all js library?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ES6 version of Javascript, try importing packages like this:

```
var Cash = require('materialize-css/js/cash');
var Component = require('materialize-css/js/component');
var Global = require('materialize-css/js/global');
var Materialize = require('materialize-css/js/buttons');
```

Hope this helps!